# Icon to represent transparency?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I am looking for ideas on how to iconically show that an element has an opaque quality.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! What have others used in the past to show opaqueness? In other words, please do your own research and work and then come back here with questions for further refinement of your concepts. Please see our [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how GDSE works and how to ask and answer questions appropriately inline with our community standards.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at icon sets such as the inkscape icons that cover many of the concepts you seem to be looking for: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Themable_icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design a transparent area above some solid geometric form or an icon with only gray and white squares (since that's how transparent background is displayed in many image editors and viewers).